# Browse and save pdf files C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, file-upload, save

I want to browse pdf files and store them in another folder. I have implemented pdf file browsing part. I can get all the pdf file path. Now I want to save them in an anther folder.
Is there any way to do this?

```
    //Keep pdf file locations
    List<string> pdfFiles = new List<string>();

    // Browse pdf and get their paths
    private void btnPdfBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                pdfFiles.Add(fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string installedPath = Application.StartupPath + "pdf";

        //Check whether folder path is exist
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(installedPath))
        {
            // If not create new folder
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(installedPath);
        }
        //Save pdf files in installedPath ??
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
```

Here is the full code snippet

```
//Keep pdf file locations
List<string> pdfFiles = new List<string>();

// Browse pdf and get their paths
private void btnPdfBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
    openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pdfFiles = new List<string>();  
        foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            pdfFiles.Add(fileName);
    }
}

private void btnUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string installedPath = Application.StartupPath + "pdf";

    //Check whether folder path is exist
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(installedPath))
    {
        // If not create new folder
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(installedPath);
    }
    //Save pdf files in installedPath
    foreach (string sourceFileName in pdfFiles) 
    {
        string destinationFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(installedPath, IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileName));
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method when you loop through all pdf's or when you want to move them [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)